# synchronized on an object monitor or in my case is better a semaphore?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, callback, thread-safety

I have a doubt if my method is thread safe or not on the contrary I pretty sure is not thread safe, but I didn't yet found a solution.
The following is my code:

```
    class TestLockSingleton
    {
       private static TestLockSingleton ourInstance = new TestLockSingleton();
    public static TestLockSingleton getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    private TestLockSingleton() {
    }

    ...
    private Object LockMonitor= new Object();

            interface Listener
        {
            void isEnable(boolean result);
        }

public void setStatus(int status){
    synchronized(LockMonitor){
        this.status = status;
        this.setted = true;
    }
}

        public void isEnable(final Listener listener){
            synchronized(LockMonitor){
                if(!setted){
                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).registerReceiver( new BroadcastReceiver() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                        synchronized(LockMonitor){
                            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                            setStatus(bundle.getInt("Status", OFFVALUE));
                            Listener.isEnable( (status==ACTIVEVALUE)?true:false );
                            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).unregisterReceiver(this);
                        }
                    }
                     },new IntentFilter(MYACTION));
                }else{
                    Listener.isEnable((status==ACTIVEVALUE)?true:false );
                }
            }

        }
    ....
    }
```

Now my problem is that I think that the method isEnable(final Listener listener) inside TestLockSingleton class is not ThreadSafe.

I don't want to handle more than one Listener, instead I have to be sure that the last who invoked the method isEnable(final Listener listener) will receive the callback.

But If two different thread calls isEnable(final Listener listener) , the last one who have invoked the method will receive two listener callback ?

EDIT : What do I want to do with this extrapolated code :

- I want register receiver only if "status" variable is not already setted from a
  precedent call to isEnable(final Listener listener), to do that I create a "setted" variable and I set it to true in the same time that I set the status variable.
- I use synchronized to prevent concurrent access to "setted" and "status" member variable
- I want to accomplish this :

  **Thread A** at time 1 invoke :

  ```
        TestLockSingleton.getInstance().isEnable(
            new Listener()
     {
                 @Override
           public void isEnable(boolean result) {

          }
    })
  ```

  **Thread B do the same thing at time 2**

  I would that only thread B receive the Listener result, I would prevent to register more than one BroadcastREceiver, because If I do that thread B receive two callback with the same result.

Comment: Can you say what you are trying to accomplish?  This code, as it stands, won't compile.  Are you trying to use synchronization to prevent more than one broadcast receiver being installed at any given time?

Comment: Hi ! Thanks to have read my question. Sorry for my bad english. I edited the first message with more explanation.
This code not compile because is only a faqsimile of my real code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like the code below.

You will have to be careful. `Listener.isEnable` will be called from multiple threads: the thread that calls `TestLockingSingleton.isEnable` and the Main thread.

```
public class TestLockSingleton {
  // ...

  public interface Listener {
    void isEnable(boolean isActive);
  }

  private static TestLockSingleton instance = new TestLockSingleton();

  public static TestLockSingleton getInstance() {
    return instance;
  }


  private final Object lock = new Object();
  private int status;
  private boolean enabled;

  private TestLockSingleton() {
  }

  public void setStatus(int status) {
    synchronized (lock) {
      this.status = status;
      this.enabled = true;
    }
  }

  public void isEnable(Context context, final Listener listener) {
    boolean enabled;
    boolean active;
    synchronized (lock) {
      enabled = this.enabled;
      active = status == ACTIVEVALUE;
    }

    if (enabled) {
      listener.isEnable(active);
      return;
    }

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).registerReceiver(
      new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          int status = intent.getExtras().getInt("Status", OFFVALUE);
          setStatus(status);
          listener.isEnable(status == ACTIVEVALUE);
          LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).unregisterReceiver(this);
        }
      },
      new IntentFilter(MYACTION));
  }

  // ...
}
```

**Edited:** to prevent `TestLockSingleton.isEnable` from holding the lock while calling `Listener.isEnable`.  Not clear whether this is desirable in this case.

Comment: This way like the mine doesn't prevent more than one broadcast receiver being registered at any given time , or I'm wrong ?
In this way Thread B in an unfortunate case it could receive two callback of listener: one from the broadcastReceiver registered by the Thread A and one to the broadcastReceiver registered by itself, or I'm wrong ?

Comment: Neither yours nor mine guarantees that there will be only one BroadcastReceiver registered at a time.  If you want to do that, you will have to use `this.enabled` to indicate that the Receiver is registered.  Have you considered registering the BroadcastReceiver permanently, and allowing the registration of only 0 or 1 listener?

Comment: Yes initially I thought to do in that way but when the status values arrived it is important to deregister the receiver.. How can allowing the resistration to only last listener?

Comment: Maybe I can resister the receiver in the SingleTon constructor, but in this way i dont know when the status value is updated then i dont know when call the listener :(

Comment: You do not need code that is anywhere near as complex as that in either your sample, or my reply.  You simply need an AtomicBoolean, gating the installation of the receiver.

Comment: Sorry I've my head melted.. can you provide me a little example ?
I can't understand how can I register receiver in the singleton constructor and correct handle the call to the listener only when the variable status is really ready to be sended to caller.